# iphone mediaplayercontroller

Tags: iphone

iam using mediaplayercontroller in iphone and in this i am able to run video from my app resorce folder but when i want to play youtube video on it then i Found Server is not Configured Error i am able to run it through two method 1)by openurl 2)mapview but when i passes url to it then it not play video i have download the sample code from apple site and i found same error for that server is not configured.. nad after seraching in thenet that this is erroo of bad url which i got from the url is it correct or not i am not sure..i am writing my code here

```
// has the user entered a movie URL?
 if (self.movieURLTextField.text.length > 0)
 {
  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.movieURLTextField.text];
  if (movieURL)
  {
   if ([movieURL scheme]) // sanity check on the URL
   {
    MoviePlayerAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MoviePlayerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // initialize a new MPMoviePlayerController object with the specified URL, and
    // play the movie
    [appDelegate initAndPlayMovie:movieURL];
   }
  }
 }
```

waiting for the fruitful result....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly link to the YouTube video from the MPMoviePlayerController.  You need to open up a UIWebView and link to the resource from there.  UIWebView detects that it is a YouTube video and handles it appropriately with the YouTube mobile app, which will subsequently return to your app.  See http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

**Edit:** To autoplay, you'll need to find the play button in the UIWebView and send it a press event(UIControlEventTouchUpInside).  The following link has an excellent example.  http://boydlee.com/2010/05/auto-playing-a-youtube-video-inside-uiwebview/

Comment: hi peter thx for the suggestion...
you are right but i want that video itself play ..without tapping on it...because  iam making an alram appliaction in which youtube video's will played hv u any idea how should i go for it....

Comment: You should comment on my answer instead of making a new one.  I'll edit my answer to include further details, which you can kindly vote up and accept if it answers your question.